# How to dynamically color cells in a GridView if amount of columns is unknown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a dynamically generated GridView with unknown amount of columns. The data in the cells is 1 and 0 (Matrix type values). Is there a way to color cells with 1s in Green and 0s in White?

CODE in ASP.NET:

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="Search" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>    
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            height: 223px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            float: left;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            height: 8px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            height: 8px;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            font-size: medium;
        }
        .auto-style8 {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 9px;
        }
        .auto-style10 {
            float: left;
            width: 768px;
            height: 61px;
            margin-left: 9px;
            margin-top: 9px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="auto-style1">
    <div class="auto-style28">    

        <img class="auto-style10" src="Images/Channel%20Map.png" /><br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    <hr width="Auto" class="auto-style5" />

        <table class="auto-style4">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2"><span style="font-family: Arial">
                    &nbsp;<span class="auto-style7">&nbsp; FILTER</span>:<br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="auto-style8" Height="25px"  Width="240px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" style="font-size: medium">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select Item" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Region     " Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="HQ         " Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="DMA        " Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Company    " Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Machine    " Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Zone       " Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style15" Height="25px" Margin-Left="-12px" Width="250px" AutoPostBack="False" style="font-size: medium" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </span> 
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Run Report" Width="104px" CssClass="auto-style25" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <span class="auto-style3"><span class="auto-style7" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: medium; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;"><span><span class="auto-style23">&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="CHANNELS FOUND: "></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </span></span></span></span>&nbsp; </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    <hr width="Auto" class="auto-style6" />

        <asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="gv_DataBound"   Width="274px" EnableModelValidation="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="rwd-table">
            <AlternatingRowStyle Wrap="False" />
            <EditRowStyle Wrap="False" /> 

            <HeaderStyle Width="75px" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="3px" Wrap="False" />
            <RowStyle Wrap="False" />
            <SelectedRowStyle Wrap="False" />
        </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConString %>" 
     SelectCommand="Usp_GetWHEREfilter" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="" FormField="ddl2" Name="Filter" Type="String" />

        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS AN EXAMPLE OF MY table:

Cells with 1ns - should be green
Cells with 0s  - should be white

```
______________________________________
COLUMNS  n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 ... n
VALUE1   1  0  1  0  0  1  ... 0 
VALUE2   0  0  1  0  1  1  ... 1
VALUE3   0  1  1  0  0  1  ... 1
VALUE4   1  1  1  0  0  1  ... 0
.....    .  .  .  .  .  .  ... .
VALUEn   1  0  1  1  0  1  ... 0
______________________________________
```

Thanks for you time and help!!!

Comment: Take a look at the [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)
Edit: Sorry, wrong class.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML markup that is generated? If you are not able to write HTML properties to use as CSS selectors, you will likely have to apply styling with Javascript

Comment: Sure, Let me update the question real quick.

Comment: I just added the markup code. Let me know if you need anything. Thanks for helping me with this! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Look at [RowDataBound Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) instead.

Comment: I checked the link you've provided. You have to specify the column name, that is my challenge, my columns are being generated dynamically. I don't know exactly what they are.

Comment: TableCellCollection (the type returned from the Cells property) implements IEnumerable. You can iterate through the collection and operate on each cell.

Comment: Can you please show me an example of doing it based on my code I've provided above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OnRowdDataBound` event for this. You will have to loop each cell and check it's value if you don't know the amount of columns in the dataset.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the rowtype is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string lastLetter = string.Empty;

        //check if cell 1 actually contains data, otherwise substring will fail
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[0].Text))
        {
            //get the last letter of the string in cell 1
            lastLetter = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Substring(e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Length - 1, 1).ToUpper();
        }

        //loop all the cells in the row
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            int value = 0;

            //try converting the cell value to an int
            try
            {
                value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            //check the value and set the background color
            if (value == 1 && lastLetter == "H")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else if (value == 1 && lastLetter == "N")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. You are the best, man!!! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: VDWWD, I have a question. I have values in 1st column that I would like to apply as a color criteria for the cells. IF 1st column row value ends with "H" THEN Green ELSE Blue.

Comment: Use this: `string lastLetter = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Substring(e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Length - 1, 1).ToUpper();`

Comment: VDWWD, is there a way to incorporate string lastLetter = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Substring(e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Length - 1, 1).ToUpper(); with the Answer you've provided above? So every cell will be colored based on 1 or 0 AND last letter in in first column (in my case it's H else N). The final createria would look like: //////////IF cell = 1 and (first column, row value = "H") THEN "Green", IF cell = 1 and (first column, row value = "N") THEN "Blue" ELSE WHITE. ////////////// That is the best I can explain it ;)

Comment: That is it! You are awesome, man! Thank you, Thank you, Thank you! =)

Comment: VDWWD, May I ask you to give me an advice on the following question I have please? Here is the link on my quiestion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008731/color-cell-in-one-gridview-based-on-cell-value-in-another-gridview?noredirect=1#comment71198595_42008731

Answer (score 1):

On RowDataBound event, try this.

```
{
           if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "n1") == 0)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }

}
```