# Color Cell in one GridView based on cell value in another GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, formatting, cell

I am trying to color a cell in GridView1 based on a value of a cell of a GridView2. Say, " If the GridView1 Column[3] Cell value = ' ' then a GridView2 Column[0] Row.Cells.BackColor = Color.Orange; ".

The following code colors the entire GridView1 and not a particular cell.

```
protected void GridView2_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string status = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Enabled"));
            if (status == "False")
            {
                GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

            }

        }
   }
```

Comment: Obviously a RowStyle will influence the display of a whole row. Why ask here instead of trying???

Comment: Taw, I did try both things. I am here for an advice.

Comment: My second RowDataBound event throws an error, "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Comment: Well you need to add checks if the DGVs have different numbers of ros and/or columns. Are you sure abut using the OnRowDataBound event? (Just asking9

Comment: Honestly, I am not entirely sure if the RowDataBound event is the best way to go in this situation. Can you recommend which route to take in order to solve my issue?

Comment: No. I don't know enough about the 'situation'. Are the DGV data-bound?

Comment: Yes, they are. I use a SQL Data Source connection to populate the grids.

Comment: I know how to condition format GridView cell Data that is within the same GridView.

Comment: However, my issue is getting cells of the GridView2 formatted using a condition based off of the GridView1

Comment: Say, " If the GridView1 Column[3] Cell value = '&nbsp;' then a GridView2 Column[0] Row.Cells.BackColor = Color.Orange; "

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet to get you started. It will look in every cell of GridView1 if there is a value that matches with the cell value currently being bound in GridView2. When there is a match it will color the cell green.

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //loop all columns in the row
        for (int i = 0; i < row.DataView.Count; i++)
        {
            string cellValue = row[i].ToString();

            //loop all rows in gridview1 
            for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                //loop all cells in gridview1
                for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    string cellValueCompare = GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[k].Text;

                    //compare values and color cell
                    if (cellValue == cellValueCompare)
                    {
                        GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[k].BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> This will only work if the columns in GridView1 are either
>   `BoundField` or `TemplateField`, auto-generated columns cannot be
>   searched.